# Batch file for loop statement

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I've put together the batch file below; I don't have much experience with batch files and I can't figure out why the file fails with an error message stating that the:

> DO command was unexpected.

Looking at the following code, does anyone know what I did wrong? Thanks.

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Set arguments supplied by Subversion 
SET REPOS = %1
SET REV = %2

REM Set working directory path 
SET WORKSPACE = D:\apache\htdocs

REM Assign changes to variable 
SET CHANGES = svnlook changed %REPOS% -r %REV% 

REM Update only changed files  
FOR /f %%a IN %CHANGES% DO svn update %%a
```

Answer (score 6):

```
FOR /f %%a IN %CHANGES% DO svn update %%a
```

should be

```
FOR /f %%a IN (%CHANGES%) DO svn update %%a
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `%CHANGES%` is not in the correct format/structure for the loop so the `DO` cannot be executed. Add the following line before the loop to check you're getting what you expected from the `SET CHANGES` command;

```
ECHO %CHANGES%
```

If the assignment is more batch code to execute you might need to use `CALL`. What are you passing in when calling the batch file for `%1` and `%2`?

Comment: Another program actually is supposed to call this batch file and pass a directory and an integer value. I added code to echo the %1 & %2 arguments; when I tested the batch file myself and passed values to it, the batch code echoed blanks indicating that the passed arguments were NOT assigned, 
i.e. post-commit.bat file:///d:/repos 10

Any idea why the arguments are not being assigned?

Comment: @Dave Anderson: Binary Worrier's suggestion is on the right track, but not quite complete; the code needs the "usebackq" option and back ticks.

Answer (score 0):

can you try to run it without the REM Statement. Comments sometimes make things work differently.

Answer (score 0):

After modifying my original code I've got it to 'work.' 
The svnlook command returns for example: trunk\images\smileyface.jpg

Currently, the for loop returns only the 'U' rather than the 'smileyface.jpg' which I want. So, while the code now works, it does function yet how I'd like (still working on it).

Below is the revamped code (Note: I had to remove all spaces between my variables and their assigned values).

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Set arguments supplied by Subversion 
SET REPOS=%1
SET REV=%2

REM Set working directory path 
SET WORKSPACE=D:\apache\htdocs

REM Assign changes to variable 
SET CHANGES=svnlook changed %REPOS% -r %REV% 

REM Update only changed files  
FOR /F "usebackq" %%a IN (`%CHANGES%`) DO (svn update %%a)
```